# Storing images in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I've been trying to store cropped images from as single frame to a list but i keep getting errors. Here's a snippet of my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/wael-karkoub/Desktop/Research/Videos/test.mp4')
ret = True
cropped_images = []
while ret == True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    _ ,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur[0:height//2],10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

    for cnt in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        image = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow('test',image)
        time.sleep(2)

    # cv2.imshow('Contours',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Output = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIhtJ.png)

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? In this code it doesn't look like you are actually ever storing any images.

Comment: @Caleb_McCreary hey i just updated the code to  my full code

Comment: can you print image's size to console?

Comment: if you want to see the output of each contour in the loop you have to change time.sleep(2) to cv2.waitKey

Comment: @Micka Yup that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your cropped images to a list, you need some assignment going on. Just add `cropped_images.append(image)` somewhere in your code, most likely after `image = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Comment: I tried doing that, but for some reason when i try to use the line "cv2.imshow()" the output crashes. I was thinking it might have to do something with the way I cropped the image

Comment: @WaelKarkoub imshow crashing would be unrelated to appending to a list. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: its not really an error, but I posted what the output looks like in the post

Comment: @WaelKarkoub That just looks like you are trying to sample bad pixels. Have you tried swapping x and y to be image = frame[x:x+w, y:y+h]? I know there can be issues with image coordinates being funky in opencv. The other issue might just be that what you've got isn't really anything. Make sure to check the image before slicing it as well.

Comment: Yeah I have tried doing that, it might be bad pixels like you said